# remove number of duplicated lines based on match before first comma

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I've large text on Linux Centos 7 server and i would like to remove lines which is matching before first comma at all

> Input:

```
112112112,00,00,00
110110,01,01,02
112112112,11,11,888
110110,99,88,8
410410,22,22,22
```

> Output:

```
410410,22,22,22
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest take a look

Comment: @Jeff Schaller  take a look

Comment: @dhag take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of `awk` two-pass solutions. The first pass stores the frequency of field 1 into an array `x`. The second pass prints a line if  `x` reports the frequency of field 1 as 1

```
awk -F, 'first_pass{x[$1]++; next}; x[$1] == 1' first_pass=1 file first_pass=0 file

awk -F, 'BEGIN{while ((getline<ARGV[1]) > 0)x[$1]++}; x[$1] == 1' file
```

Comment: so i can use one of those command or must applied together?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, you may use either

Comment: @iruvar any reason to use variable instead of idiomatic `NR==FNR` in the first solution?

Comment: @Sundeep, this is something  I picked up from the great Stephane Chazelas - `NR == FNR` does not always guarantee first file due to the fact that it reports true for the second file when the first file has no records in it. I've adopted the variable approach ever since

Comment: ah ok, good to know :) however with `next` in play here, it won't be an issue here :)

Comment: @Sundeep, I don't think `next` has anything to do with it.

Comment: I meant that in usage like `NR==FNR{<array code>; next} <print code>` won't face any issue even if first file has no records..

Comment: @Sundeep, in this particular case it would not make a diff. I am generically referring to the `NR == FNR { print "first file"; next}; {print "second file"}'` situation, which fails badly with a zero byte first file. As with quoting shell variables, better safe than sorry

Comment: @iruvar and in case if i would like to view the duplicated lines based on the same example i provided ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, change `x[$1] == 1` to `x[$1] > 1`

Comment: @iruvar Thank You a Lot " PRINCE"

Answer (score 0):

Short GNU **`datamash`** + **`sed`** combination:

```
datamash -sft',' -g1 count 1 <file | sed -n 's/,1$//p'
```

The 1st process of the above pipeline will count the number of items in each group of the 1st field values (grouped by `-g1`) adding resulting counts as the last field